# JAVA: How to take Pearson correlation of iris matrix?

Tags: java, matrix, correlation, pearson

I read iris data set from file "iris.txt"and store it into arraylist. Now i need some help that how to take Pearson correlation of that matrix using formula, as matrix consist of 150 rows and 4 columns.I need just a little push up so i can continue in my project further. Thanks

Comment: Please report the answer if you found it.